# How to decrypt cart id for guest customer through a plugin

Tags: magento2, plugin

I have this aroundSavePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder method in my plugin and my goal is to get the quote information during payment. For some reason the quote id for guest customer is encrypted. Does anyone know how can I decrypt it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
{
  ........

  /**
  * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory
  */
  protected $quoteIdMaskFactory;


 }
 public function __construct(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMaskFactory $quoteIdMaskFactory){

    $this->quoteIdMaskFactory =$quoteIdMaskFactory;
 }
  ....................

  /**
  * @param string $quoteId
  * @return int
  */
  public function decrypt($quoteId){
     $quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($quoteId, 'masked_id');

     return $quoteIdMask->getQuoteId();
  }
```